# History order comment not show when export order in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I have three field comment, this can save after order. It work and show on order history comment like this

[image]

But when i export xml it not show, i think problem at here, 2 links are the same. 2 comment not show, invoice comment showing.

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../entity/comment"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="../../entity/comment"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="../../invoice_comments/invoice_comment/comment"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect answer -- not about the XSL export process. That info is in the `sales_flat_invoice_comment` column `comment`. Below is a MySql query which exposed the order comments for me (which I renamed that column to `order_note`):

```
SELECT sfo.entity_id, increment_id, customer_id, grand_total, sfo.shipping_amount, tax_amount, discount_amount, subtotal 
, customer_email AS 'email', customer_firstname AS 'firstname', customer_lastname AS 'lastname' 
, sfop.method, cc_type, cc_last4, sfop.additional_information as 'pmt_details', sfic.comment AS 'order_note' 
, total_item_count AS 'order_lines_count', total_qty_ordered, sfo.created_at, sfo.updated_at 
, remote_ip, shipping_description, customer_group_id, billing_address_id, shipping_address_id 
, tm_field1 AS 'year', tm_field2 AS 'make', tm_field3 AS 'model', coupon_code 
, tax_percent, customer_is_guest, customer_note 
FROM sales_flat_order AS `sfo` 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_payment AS `sfop` ON sfop.parent_id = sfo.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_invoice_comment AS `sfic` ON sfic.parent_id = sfo.entity_id 
WHERE sfo.status = 'complete'
```